# jQuery Mobile: How to navigate between dynamically generated pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) the code below does the following...

1) It generates menu items and adds them to the index page.

2) It creates actual pages for the menu items.

Now when I click on a menu item it does not seem to move to that page? I can see in the markup the pages exist with the correct id's.

This is what I have so far.

```
$.each(siteData["pages"], function(i,v) {
   $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content]').append('' +
       '<a href='+ v["id"] + ' data-role="button">' + v["name"] + '</a>').trigger('create');

        // Prepare your page structure
        var newPage = $("<div data-role='page' id=>" + v["id"] +
           "<div data-role=header><a data-iconpos='left' data-icon='back' href='#' data-role='button' data-rel='back'>Back</a>" +
                         "<h1>Dynamic Page</h1>" +
                         "</div>" +
                         "<div data-role=content>Stuff here</div>" +
                         "</div>");

                 // Append the new page info pageContainer
                 newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);



             });
```

**markup**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="navlist"></div>    
</div>
```

**How do I navigate between dynamically generated pages?**

Could someone give me an example using my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you have few errors.

Take a look at my working example, it is made out of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3kPTf/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role=content]').append('<a href="#second" data-role="button">Second</a>').trigger('create');

    var newPage = $("<div data-role='page' id='second'><div data-role=header><a data-iconpos='left' data-icon='back' href='#' data-role='button' data-rel='back'>Back</a>" +
                         "<h1>Dynamic Page</h1>" +
                         "</div>" +
                         "<div data-role=content>Stuff here</div>" +
                         "</div>");

    // Append the new page info pageContainer
    newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);    

});
```

- First error, close an a tag inside a button and give it a # tag.
- Your dynamic page div is not closed properly